# What is the best way to search forward/backward for a token?

Tags: search, string, isearch, words

Sometimes I want to search for a specific word but I don't want to find words which have my search string as a substring.

For example, if I search for "**pan**" (bread, in Spanish), I don't want to find the words "ex**pan**sión", "se**pan**", or "**pan**orama". A partial work around would be to search for " **pan** " (with spaces around), but in this case, I will not find the word "**pan**" when it is at the end of the sentence ("**pan.**") or near a comma ("**pan,**").

Is there a straightforward way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You used tag `isearch` so presumably you want to search *interactively*, not using Lisp. And you used tag `words`; you apparently want to search for a whole **word**.

In that case, just use **`M-s w`**, which does `isearch-forward-word` at the top-level, and which does `isearch-toggle-word` from within Isearch.

See the Emacs manual, node [Word Search](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Word-Search.html).

(I found that information in the manual by just doing `i word search`.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`#'isearch-forward-regexp`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Search.html#Regexp-Search) to search with a regex instead of a bare string. This function is bound to `C-M-s` by default.

So, we can search for `\bpan\b`. [`\b`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Backslash.html) is a word boundary -- so it matches "the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word". So we search for a word boundary, then the word "pan", then another word boundary.

Alternately, passing a prefix argument to `#'isearch-forward` (which is bound to `C-s` by default) does an incremental search by regex. So you'd  type `C-u C-s`.